# WordPress Redux Framework - Redux admin folder can't find plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I'm trying to get the Redux Framework working with my "blankslate" theme. I installed the plugin (downloaded the latest zip for Redux). Then I used the Redux Builder tool to create an admin folder. I copied the admin folder to my themes folder. The Redux menu item was successfully added to WordPress' left nav (in my case I named it CMS) and all the fields work and can be saved. But there is constantly an error that says "This theme recommends the following plugin: Redux Framework." Redux is obviously installed, so how can I get this error to go away? I'm sure there's just a configuration option somewhere that needs to be set.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are loading TGM before Redux has had a chance to load. Delay calling TGM until after a hook like this:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'tgm_init_function', 25);
```

This will force all the plugins to load before it tries to run TGM. My guess is your plugin is named higher in the alphabet than Redux, and thus it's loaded first.  ;)

Comment: P.S. Lead dev of Redux here.  ;)

Comment: It would be best to use the issue tracker: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-extensions/issues